# How to use expressions in Elasticsearch REST request body?

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

Is it possible to use expressions within Elasticsearch REST API body? I am aware that you can use date-math expressions in the REST query string but I can't seem to find an example of it working in the REST request body.

My goal is to create an ILM policy and index template that will rollover the indices and account for the daily change of the date on the index name. An example of an index name would be i.e. index-2020.12.17

```
PUT /_index_template/index_template
{
  "index_patterns": ["%3Cindex-%7Bnow%2Fd%7D%3E"],                 
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 1,
      "index.lifecycle.name": "index_policy",      
      "index.lifecycle.rollover_alias": "%3Cindex-%7Bnow%2Fd%7D%3E"    
    },
    "aliases": {
    "%3Cindex-%7Bnow%2Fd%7D%3E": {
        "is_write_index": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way ILM works.

- `index_patterns` should simply by a wildcard that matches your index names
- `rollover_alias` should be a constant string that applications write to
- you don't need to define any `alias` for ILM to work, it's what `rollover_alias` is for.

So your index template definition should simply be like this:

```
PUT /_index_template/index_template
{
  "index_patterns": ["index-*"],                 
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 1,
      "index.lifecycle.name": "index_policy",      
      "index.lifecycle.rollover_alias": "index-write"    
    },
    "aliases": {
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can [bootstrap](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html#ilm-gs-alias-bootstrap) the initial index with:

```
PUT index-2020.12.17-000001
{
  "aliases": {
    "index-write": {
      "is_write_index": true
    }
  }
}
```

Then your client application (Filebeat, Logstash, etc) can simply send their data to `index-write` and all the rolling over is taken care of by whatever policy you've defined in the `index_policy` lifecycle policy.

```
PUT index-write/_doc/1
{ ... }
```

As of 7.9, there's an easier way using [data streams](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html#ilm-gs-apply-policy) that doesn't need any bootstrapping like we did above. All you need to do is to create your index template like this:

```
PUT /_index_template/index_template
{
  "index_patterns": ["index"],                 
  "data_stream": {},
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 1,
      "index.lifecycle.name": "index_policy"   
    }
  }
}
```

And then you can simply index your data like this

```
PUT index/_doc/1
{ ... }
```

Behind the scene, data stream indexes will be created and rolled over for you according to the `index_policy` lifecycle policy.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have date-math expression in Rest API, for more information you can check ES offical documentation here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date-math-index-names.html.

For ILM policy you can find information here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html